# Adding an image and a button onto a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have this JFrame below:

```
public class TestJFrame extends JFrame {
    public RecyclingMachinesGui(String title) {
        super (title);

        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        Panel r = new Panel();
        Jbutton j = new JButton("Recycle Item");
        r.add(j);
        container.add(r);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);      
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class Panel extends JPanel {
        private BufferedImage image;

        public Panel() {
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(new File("./temp.png"));
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.getMessage().toString();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code in my main method when I run `new TestJFrame()` for some reason I only see the `JButton j` inside my `Panel` (which I added to my container) and do not see an image inside the panel. Is the `paintComponent` method in my Panel not being called?

I want to have a picture on the top and the button on the bottom of the Panel. Can anyone explain why this is not happening?

Comment: Is the image been loaded? If you want display the image at the top and button at the panel, use a `BorderLayout`, wrap the image in a `JLabel` and add it to the center position and the button to south position

Comment: Use a border layout for the `Panel` class?

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: @1290 No, one the `contentPane`

Comment: But wouldn't I want borderlayout on the Panel? So I can put the image on the NORTH and the button on the SOUTH?

Comment: @1290 You could, if that's desired effect, I'm just saying you don't actually need the `Panel` or the custom painting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image in your `Panel` is not displayed,
because the `Panel` has no proper **preferred size**.
Therefore the LayoutManager (the `FlowLayout`) doesn't know which size
to give to the Panel, and gives it the size of a very small square.
Hence, your `Panel`'s `paintComponent` is actually called,
but it is painting only on an invisible small area,

You can fix it easily in your `Panel`'s constructor,
by calling `setPreferredSize` immediately after loading your image:

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File("./temp.png"));
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
```

Comment: *"You can fix it easily.."* ..by using a `JLabel` to display the image.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to have a picture on the top and the button on the bottom of the Panel. Can anyone explain why this is not happening?

Okay, so you don't really need to paint the image yourself, a `JLabel` will do very nicely itself, then you just need to use a `BorderLayout` to add the label to the center and the button to the south, for example...

```
public class TestJFrame extends JFrame {
    public RecyclingMachinesGui(String title) {
        super (title);

        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JPanel r = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        try {
            r.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("./temp.png")))));
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage().toString();
        }
        Jbutton j = new JButton("Recycle Item");
        r.add(j, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        container.add(r);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);      
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Your current approach would place the button OVER the image, which is great if you want to use the image as a background

Comment: It's an idea based on your comments, so I'm not 100% sure if it will meet with you overall requirements, but it's another way to achieve what you seem to be trying to do ;)

Comment: Ahh ok this way makes much more sense. I will go with this method. Thank you! Just out of curiosity in my `Panel` subclass when exactly is the PaintComponent method called? When I instantiate the `Panel` subclass? EDIT: This is exactly what I needed. :)

Comment: @1290 You `paintComponent` won't be called until the component is "realised" on the screen, a number of things need to take place, but lets just say, it needs to be added to a container and that container needs to be attached to a visible window/frame before your component can be painted ... as a shortish description ;)